# How to add subtitles/subcaptions to huxtable regression table?

Tags: r-markdown

I've looked through the official [huxtable documentation](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/reference/index.html) and I didn't see anything about how to set anything other than one main title (`caption` or `set_caption`), per regression table. If anyone has an idea how to set a subtitle below a main caption/title at the top of a table, I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Here's a toy example of regression table. I can set the caption at the top easily.  How do I add a subtitle?

```
data(mtcars)

model1 <- lm(mpg~cyl, data = mtcars)
model2 <- lm(mpg~cyl + hp, data = mtcars)

huxtable::huxreg(model1, model2) %>% set_caption("TABLE A.")
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way currently. (File a [feature request](https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues/new/choose) maybe.) One workaround is to embed newlines in your caption. Here's an example for TeX:

```r
library(huxtable)
hux(1:5, 1:5) %>% 
  set_caption("Title\\\\Subtitle") %>% 
  set_caption_pos("top") %>% 
  quick_pdf()
```

For HTML, you'd use "<br>" rather than the backslashes.